# Доступ к переменным/массиву. Выделение памяти под массив

Tags: objective-c

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть простейший калькулятор. Который умеет только складывать два числа.
Я хочу, чтобы после нажатия рассчитать, число введенное в один из текстбоксов записалось в массив и в конце вывести массив на консоль.

```
 @interface my : NSObject{
      IBOutlet NSTextField *numberOne;
      IBOutlet NSTextField *numberTwo;
      IBOutlet NSTextField *result;
      NSMutableArray *myArray;
    }

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;

@end
```

Реализация

```
@implementation my
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
  int a = [numberOne intValue];
  int b = [numberTwo intValue];
  int sum = a + b;
  [result setIntValue:sum];
  NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[numberOne intValue]];
  [myArray addObject:number];
  NSLog(@"%@",myArray);

}
@end
```

Никак не пойму где надо инициализировать и выделить память под массив myArray, чтобы достучаться до него в методе calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать прямо в методе `-calculate:`

```
- (IBAction)calculate: (id)sender {
  int a = [numberOne intValue];
  int b = [numberTwo intValue];
  [result setIntValue: (a + b)];
  NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[numberOne intValue]];

  // Создаём массив, если ещё этого не сделали 
  if (!myArray) {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }

  [myArray addObject: [numberOne integerValue]];
  NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
}
```

Либо в методе `-init`, который вызывается при инициализации вашего объекта класса `my`:

```
- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Инициализация остальных переменных
    // ...
  }

  return (self);
}
```

В любом случае не забудьте освободить выделенную под массив память в методе `-dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {

  [myArray release];
  // тут освобождение памяти из-под других переменных
  // …

  [super dealloc];
}
```

---

**Добавлено:**

1. Действительно, `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` есть только у [класса-делегата](http://www.macbug.ru/macosxapp.php) приложения (обычно такой класс называется `*AppDelegate`). Остальные же классы можно (очень грубо) разделить на две категории, в каждой из которой есть свои особенности первичной инициализации переменных:

   1) Классы, которые создаются динамически в ходе выполнения программы.
   Здесь принятно проводить первичную инициализацию в методах:

   - `-init`
   - `-initWithCoder:`
   - `-initWithFrame:` // для классов, наследуемых от NSView/UIView
   - `-initWithNibName:` // [для классов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129557/), наследуемых от [NS/UI]ViewController

   Почему именно `-init*`? Давайте посмотрим на пример создания такого объекта:

   ```
   MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
                             ^^^^^
   NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   2) Классы, загружаемые из .nib файлов.
   Они выполняют инициализацию в таких методах, как

   - `-initWithFrame:`
   - `-initWithCoder:`
   - `-awakeFromNib`, который, по правде, вызывается уже [*после*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377202/which-should-i-use-awakefromnib-or-viewdidload) того, как объект будет загружен в память и (*должен быть*) проиницилизирован;
2. Для того, чтобы вывести содержимое массива в виде строки, у NSArray существует специальный метод [`-componentsJoinedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:)

   ```
    // myArray = {@"Mike", @"Landon", @"Bill"};
    NSString *everything = [myArray componentsJoinedByString: @", "];
    // everything = @"Mike, Landon, Bill";
    [textView insertText: everything];
   ```
3. Можно ли как-то достать из массива элемент по индексу?
   В современных компиляторах (читайте, Xcode) существует поддержка т.н. [*subscripting*](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/) «из коробки»:

   ```
   id first = myArray[0];
   ```

   Либо можно воспользоваться  старым вариантом:

   ```
   id first = [myArray objectAtIndex: 0];
   ```

Comment: Да, именно так я и сделал, но вопрос в том, что бы хранить все введенные числа в один из текстбоксов. Смысл в том, что массив будет постоянно инициализироваться заного после нажатия кнопки calculate и хранить он будет только 1 число.  А мне надо, чтобы в нем хранилась "история" всех введенных слагаемых.

Comment: @Игорь Васильев, массив не будет инициироваться заново. За это отвечает условие  `if (!myArray)`, которое истинно лишь при первом вызове `-calculate:`.

Comment: @VioLet, А ведь и правда. Не заметил. 
Ну хорошо, допустим, а как по другому сделать? Ну на пример в c#  я бы инициализировал такой массив при загрузке формы и он был бы доступен мне из того же обработчика события click на эквивалентную кнопку calculate. А как такое сделать в objective c?

Comment: @VioLet, Я думал наследовать класс, дефолтный, отвечающий за отображение окна, AppDelegate от NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>  и там есть такой метод applicationWillFinishLaunching и в нем инициализировать нужный мне массив, но он не видим в моем классе my. Или так же успешно можно и "my" наследовать от NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> и в my определять метод applicationWillFinishLaunching.
P.S тяжеловато как-то адаптироваться к objective c=)

Comment: И ещё 1 вопрос, который возник у меня.
Теперь я хочу содержимое массива(NSMutableArray) вывести в TextView. 
Тут очередные проблемы. Я пытаюсь поиграться с вьюшными формами, что бы понять как вообще с ними работать. Пока не очень хорошо все это дается.
Собственно к проблеме. Есть у меня переменная типа NSTextView, которая связана с самой textview, и просто строку текста у меня получается записать в TextView, а вот массив- нет.
И попутно ещё 1 вопрос. Можно ли как-то достать из массива элемент по индексу? Аля c# mass[1]
Буду очень вам благодарен если вы найдете время и ответите на мои вопросы.